# Mypy does not respect setting in mypy.ini to exclude folder from checking when called from VS Code

Tags: python, virtualenv, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, mypy

I would like to exclude a folder from the mypy checks.
Looking at the documentation I tried the following configuration in my mypy.ini configuration file

```
[mypy]  
python_version = 3.8  
exclude '/venv/'
```

with no luck.

I want to exclude my virtual environment from mypy checking. I only one to type check the code that I write.

Is it a bug from mypy?

I am using mypy 0.901 and mypy-extensions 0.4.3. Also I am using mypy vs-code extension 0.2.0.

Comment: You'll probably need to remove the quotation marks: `exclude = /venv/`, and maybe the initial `/` as well:  `exclude = venv/` (depending on whether `venv` is a sibling of your ini file or located somewhere deeper)

Comment: It does not work. It generates the following error:
mypy.ini: [mypy]: Unrecognized option: exclude = venv/

Comment: What version of mypy are you using? The exclude option was added in 0.810.

Comment: mypy              0.901  
and
mypy-extensions   0.4.3
Also I was using mypy vs-code extension 0.2.0 that was released last month. It looks like reverting back to 0.1.5 fixed the issue. Not sure yet.

Comment: Huh, very strange

Comment: you missed the `=` and mypy is pretty unhelpful.

Answer (score 33):

The issue is that VS Code is invoking `mypy` file by file. And `mypy` doesn't use the exclude option when invoked on a single file. The workaround is using `python.linting.ignorePatterns` in the settings.json.

```json
 "python.linting.ignorePatterns": [ "venv/**/*.py" ]
```

More info about the behaviour of [exclude](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html#cmdoption-mypy-exclude):

> Note that this flag only affects recursive discovery, that is, when mypy is discovering files within a directory tree or submodules of a package to check. If you pass a file or module explicitly, it will still be checked. For instance, mypy --exclude '/setup.py$' but_still_check/setup.py.

I would still exclude this in the config file, for completeness’ sake, in case you run `mypy` by hand.

```
[mypy]
exclude = venv
```

Comment: Depends on the extension in use Microsoft's version of this check my very well be per file. There is also an independent mypy extension that uses the workspace folder as its default for starting mypyd.

Comment: What would the glob pattern for `python.linting.ignorePatterns` look like when ignoring a directory and all of its subdirectories?

Comment: What `settings.json` file? Where?

Comment: @cowlinator , the settings.json holds all your vscode configurations. You can open it with `ctrl+shift+p` and then typing *settings* in the search bar.

Comment: `python.linting.ignorePatterns` is now deprecated. It can be replaced with `python.analysis.ignore` which I guess will apply to any configured linter, not just mypy

Answer (score 21):

If I want to ignore my `venv` folder, then I write the following lines to the `mypy.ini` file:

```
[mypy]
exclude = venv
```

Comment: In VSCode depending on the extension in use this my be by passed. See the next answer in that case.

Comment: Works in setup.cfg too.

Answer (score 18):

Ignoring more than one directory.

`pyproject.toml`:

```ini
[tool.mypy]
exclude = ['venv', '.venv']
```

`mypy --config-file pyproject.toml ./`

Comment: do you mean `project.toml` or `pyproject.toml`?

Comment: It automatically reads pyproject.toml and you can skip specifying it manually.

Answer (score 9):

According to the [official doc](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config_file.html#confval-exclude), if using `mypy.ini` or `setup.cfg`, the content of the `exclude` field in the configuration file seems have to be a regular expression, e.g.:

```
[mypy]
exclude = (?x)(
    ^one\.py$    # files named "one.py"
    | two\.pyi$  # or files ending with "two.pyi"
    | ^three\.   # or files starting with "three."
  )
```

On the other hand, if you use `pyproject.toml` as the configuration file, the content of the `exclude` field could be of two forms: (1) a single regular expression (as above); (2) an array of strings as follows:

```
[tool.mypy]
exclude = [
    "^one\\.py$",  # TOML's double-quoted strings require escaping backslashes
    'two\.pyi$',  # but TOML's single-quoted strings do not
    '^three\.',
]
```

So, it seems that using an array of file/dir-names (not a RegEx) be not allowed for MyPy, which is different from that of `flake8` (just only an array of file/dir-names is OK).

Comment: This should be the top answer. I was always wondering, why the other approaches don't work for me. Thanks

Comment: Does not appear to work.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, the issue was the vscode linting in my tests folder.  The solution listed above ( "python.linting.ignorePatterns": [ "test" ]) likely would have worked, but I didn't want to disable linting there completely.  What worked for me was adding this to my mypy.ini:

```
[mypy]
# global config here

[mypy-test.*] # the folder I wanted ignored was named "test" and is in the root of my workspace.
ignore_errors = True
```

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me after some trial and error:

```
[mypy]
python_version = 3.9
disallow_untyped_defs = True
ignore_missing_imports = True
exclude = ['env/']
```

Comment: that excluded my whole project lol. the only thing that seems to work is just plain `exclude = venv/` with no quotes.

Comment: I made the venv dir named 'env'. This was the only thing that worked for me. I'm on linux, perhaps that might influence the results.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment of my answer, Microsoft's Mypy extensions has experimental(as the write) setting: `mypy-type-checker.reportingScope`.
Setting this option to `workspace` and restarting mypy server helped me to disable mypy checks in my tests directory.

```json
// settings.json
"mypy-type-checker.reportingScope": "workspace"
```

```ini
# pyproject.toml
[tool.mypy]
exclude =  ["tests"]
```