# Mypy library and Django exclude app directories

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, mypy

I have several apps in my Django project, but I wanted to exclude directories or apps, how can this be done.

Below is my mypy.ini file, but it doesn't work :

```
[mypy]
ignore_missing_imports = True
exclude = customers
```

As you can see above `customers` is one of my django apps (directory), what could be the best solution here?

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by "doesn't work". We need at least to understand your problem to answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exclude folder from mypy checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67905546/exclude-folder-from-mypy-checking). To sum up, you can either alter `follow_imports` or set `ignore_errors = True` in override section for your module (`[mypy-customers] ignore_errors = true`).